# Comma in CSS, multiple selectors using the same CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

```
.Resource table.Tbl td
{ /* some css*/ }

.Resource table.Tbl td.num
{ /* some css 2*/ }

.Resource table.Tbl td.num span.icon
{ /* some css 3*/ }

.Resource table.Tbl2 td
{ /* some css*/ }

.Resource table.Tbl2 td.num
{ /* some css 2*/ }

.Resource table.Tbl2 td.num span.icon
{ /* some css 3*/ }
```

where the CSS for Tbl and Tbl2 should be the same.

```
.Resource table.Tbl, table.Tbl2 td { /* some css*/ }
```

doesn't work.

How can I achieve this, without duplicating whole line?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
.Resource table.Tbl td, .Resource table.Tbl2 td { /* some css*/ }
```

You should add the full ancestor path for both rules. Not just where you see differences.

Comment: This is really important. The other suggestion can lead to all kinds of confusion because the second part of the selector `table.Tbl2 td` is not restricted to the `.Resource` class as implied.

Answer (score 11):

```
.Resource table.Tbl td, .Resource table.Tbl2 td { /* some css */ }
```

You have to duplicate the stuff before and after `table.TblX`, because there's no way to group the `,` operator to have higher precedence than the descendent selector  .

Answer (score 5):

You can't (well not on every browser, read on).

Each selector is independent, unfortunately.

It is one of [CSS's annoying issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Limitations).

There is [`:any()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3aany), which can do what you wish, but browser support is limited.

You can do it anyway you like and pre-process it with a server side language, so it outputs independent selectors.

[LESS](http://lesscss.org/) is popular.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use the [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) CSS pseudo-class function to fix the precedence of your [selector lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Selector_list).

---

The problem here is that the syntax for selector lists in CSS treats the comma as having as a very low precedence, below that of [combinators](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#selector-combinator) (like space) meaning that if you write this:

```
.Resource table.Tbl, table.Tbl2 td { /* some css*/ }
```

Then browsers will treat that as equivalent to:

```
.Resource table.Tbl { /* some css */ }
table.Tbl2 td { /* some css */ }
```

Which is probably not what you meant.

If instead you want something that's equivalent to:

```
.Resource table.Tbl td { /* some css */ }
.Resource table.Tbl2 td { /* some css */ }
```

Then you can express that in CSS using the [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) pseudo-class function:

```
.Resource :is(table.Tbl, table.Tbl2) td { /* some css*/ }
```

There's also [`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) which is similar, but with a lower [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

`:is()` and `:where()` are supported in all major browsers, but not in Internet Explorer.