# How to apply CSS to the first letter after :before content?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p:before {  
    content:"Former - "; 
    color:red;
    font-family:"Tahoma" ,Times New Roman;
    font-size:70%;
}

p.normal:first-letter {
    font-size:40px;
    color:blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="normal">First character of this paragraph will
  be normal and will have font size 40px;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, the content in the `:before` pseudo-element is displaying in red, but I also want to style the character "F" of "**F**irst character of this paragraph" in blue. But instead, I see the "F" of "**F**ormer - " in blue.

What I want is to apply both `:before` and first letter of `.normal` *after* the `:before` content to the same paragraph. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css selector: first paragraph's first letter inside a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721730/css-selector-first-paragraphs-first-letter-inside-a-div)

Comment: And if you want to know how to use the same rules for multiple selectors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013604/comma-in-css-multiple-selectors-using-the-same-css. As for book/site suggestions: Such subjective questions are off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I bit the bullet and gave the question a much-needed rewrite.

Comment: @Felix Kling: After a series of misguided edits I've come to determine that this is asking something quite different.

Comment: @BoltClock: I was not sure in which order the rules are applied. +1 for your effort.

Comment: FWIW: *if* you can, you can change `:before` to `:after`, and just use absolute positioning to place it before the container visually, but still be after it semantically (and thus allowing `::first-child` to work); it's not a good enough solution for me to post it as an answer, but IMVHO it has its merits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can not edit the HTML without JavaScript for example, you can use pure CSS so long as you are styling the :before or :after content of a "block-level" element.

```css
p:before {
  content: 'Wisdom'
}

p:first-letter {
  font-size: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Please note: The `::first-letter` CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first letter of the first line of a block-level element, but only when not preceded by other content (such as images or inline tables).

Attribution: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Answer (score 9):

Normally you would do this with the `:first-letter` pseudo-element, but seeing as you have `:before` content, which [inserts text *before* the actual content of your paragraph](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content), then rather than the first letter of the actual content, `:first-letter` would match the first letter of the `:before` content instead.

That means that instead of this:

```
<p class="normal">
  <p:before>Former - </p:before>
  <p.normal:first-letter>F</p.normal:first-letter>irst character of this paragraph will
  be normal and will have font size 40px;
</p>
```

You actually get this:

```
<p class="normal">
  <p:before>
    <p.normal:first-letter>F</p.normal:first-letter>ormer - 
  </p:before>
  First character of this paragraph will
  be normal and will have font size 40px;
</p>
```

Due to how CSS generated content works, I don't think there's a solution in pure CSS to reach the first letter of the actual content once you have inserted content before it.

As an alternative, you could use a `span` in place of the `:first-letter` pseudo-element, to which you can then apply the blue color, but that means you have to insert extra elements:

```
  <p class="normal"><span>F</span>irst character of this paragraph will
  be normal and will have font size 40px;</p>
```

```css
p.normal span {
    font-size:40px;
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: ... or you can change `:before` to `:after`, and just use absolute positioning to place it before the container visually, but still be after it semantically (and thus allowing ::first-child to work). I dunno if that makes more sense than just `<span class="firstletter">` etc, but at least the clutter is moved from the HTML to CSS that way.

Answer (score 1):

change :before to :after, and just use absolute positioning , as user719662 suggested

```
p:after {  
  position: absolute;
left: 0;
content:"Former - "; 
color:red;
font-family:"Tahoma" ,Times New Roman;
font-size:70%;
}

p.normal:first-letter {
  font-size:40px;
color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <title>Complicated pseudo element and span</title>

    <style type="text/css">
      <!--
      p:before {  
           content:"Read this -"; 
           color:red;
           font-family:"Tahoma" ,Times New Roman;
           font-size:100%;}

            .span {
                   font-size:40px;
              color:blue; 
                 } 

         -->
   </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <p><span style="color:blue; font-size:30px" >F</span>irst character of this paragraph
        will be normal and will have font size 40px;</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for guideline-I got my OUTPUT THE way i imagine and I want it